# how to write a formula based on quantity field

Tags: formula, formula-field, image-formula

i have an requirement , i have field like quantity it is number field and i have a field like batch number it is text field , and i have written a validation rule on batchnumber with regex function ,the format is "bb:1#cc:2#dd:6" and my requirement is if i entered in quantity field ex 30 and the batch number it will only accept the format like "bb:10#cc:10#dd:10" means it has to add the quantity and  enter in batchnumber , both fields it should have the quantity  and batchnumber is to equal when they add both the fields can any one let me know the solution for this .

Regards,
Teja.

Comment: How are you populating both of these two fields? manually while creating the record? and what will happen if you delete any of these two field values?

Comment: Hi ,  it is populated by manually  by user if we delete the field value it cant be  submitted

Comment: Hi , i have written the validation rule on batch number  by using regex function , were can i place your below code in below validation rule can you pls help on this

Comment: my validation rule is AND($RecordType.DeveloperName ="Return", 
ISPICKVAL($User.PFE_Country__c,"PR") , 
(NOT(REGEX(PFE_Batch_Number__c,"[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[:][0-9]{1}[0-9]*"))), 
(NOT(REGEX(PFE_Batch_Number__c,"[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[:][0-9]{1}[0-9]*[#][a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[:][0-9]{1}[0-9]*"))), 
(NOT(REGEX(PFE_Batch_Number__c,"[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[:][0-9]{1}[0-9]*[#][a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[:][0-9]{1}[0-9]*[#][a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[:][0-9]{1}[0-9]*"))))

Comment: please place the below code in properly pls send it to me .

Comment: based on the validation rule were i have to keep the below code and it is formula field or validtion rule can you pls help  me how to get this requirement pls

Comment: hi , how to do this with trigger  can you please send the code to me it is very useful to me

Answer (score 0):

Given that your REGEX can validate the Batch Number format, I find that to develop the Validation Rule I use several formula fields for readability and then a simple Validation Rule. This makes debugging easy and the resulting VR is easy to follow for the next admin who takes over your work.

Five formula fields:

**FirstColonIx__c**

```
FIND(':',  Batch_Number__c )
```

**SecondColonIx__c**

```
FIND(':',  Batch_Number__c  , FirstHashIx__c)
```

**ThirdColonIx__c**

```
FIND(':',  Batch_Number__c , SecondHashIx__c)
```

**FirstHashIx__c**

```
FIND('#',  Batch_Number__c)
```

**SecondHashIx__c**

```
FIND('#', Batch_Number__c, FirstHashIx__c+1 )
```

**Validation Rule**

```
(
VALUE(MID( Batch_Number__c , FirstColonIx__c+1, FirstHashIx__c-FirstColonIx__c-1)) +

VALUE(MID( Batch_Number__c , SecondColonIx__c+1, SecondHashIx__c-SecondColonIx__c-1)) +

VALUE(MID( Batch_Number__c , ThirdColonIx__c+1,  LEN( Batch_Number__c) - ThirdColonIx__c  ))

) 

<> Quantity__c
```

Of course, you could do this all in APEX trigger in a lot less code but you asked for a formula